# Session store not set on request. Lumen

Tags: php, laravel, session, lumen, laravel-socialite

I am currently working on a project with Lumen.
I want to use Socialite to allow the user to authenticate through Twitter but I have had this error since "Session store not set on request"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since HTTP driven applications are stateless, by default lumen doesn't enable session functionality. In order to enable it, you must uncomment all of the middleware within the $app->middleware() method call in your bootstrap/app.php file.

Comment: I am using the 7.2.0 version

Comment: Lumen Now supports only stateless http.. from  =>5.2.* Removed session

Comment: check this out https://lumen.laravel.com/docs/5.2/releases